# Is there any way to trigger delete event from outlook web add-ins

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to delete the current outlook web event from custom add-in created using task pane. Is there any way to capture the delete event of item from custom button click inside task pane. Please see the below screenshot for the same.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0ct.png)

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on the scenario? OfficeJs does not provide APIs to delete an event but you can [use REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) to delete the item.

Comment: We have already deleted event using REST APIs.

Comment: Ok, REST API response would be confirmation of deletion. Can you help us with scenario you are trying to achieve?